# Prove that one function is bigger than another - 2 variable case

Tags: functions, derivatives

What I want to prove is that:

$$f(\alpha, \beta )>g(\alpha, \beta)$$

Where:

$$f(\alpha, \beta)=(2\alpha^4-6\beta\alpha^3+9\beta^2\alpha^2-8\beta^3\alpha+3\beta^4)N$$

$$g(\alpha, \beta)=\alpha^4-6\beta\alpha^3+12\beta^2\alpha^2-10\beta^3\alpha+3\beta^4$$

Given:

$$\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^+$$
$$\alpha \neq\beta$$
$$N \in   \left\{ 2,3,4,...\right\}$$
 (not sure if the second constraint is necessary)

What I have in mind but are not able to do is the following in a one variable case. I would first prove:

$$f(0)=g(0)$$

And then Show that:

$$f'(\gamma)>g'(\gamma)\  \  \forall\  \gamma>0$$

Is this also possible for two variables as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By homogeneity, it suffices to consider the case $\beta = 1$.  Moreover, $f(\alpha, 1) \ge 0$, so it suffices to consider $N=2$.
If
$$\eqalign{h(\alpha) &= 2 (2 \alpha^4 - 6 \alpha^3 + 9 \alpha^2 - 8 \alpha + 3) - (\alpha^4 - 6 \alpha^3 + 12 \alpha^2 - 10 \alpha + 3) \cr &= 3\,{\alpha}^{4}-6\,{\alpha}^{3}+6\,{\alpha}^{2}-6\,\alpha+3}$$
then $h'(\alpha)$ has one real root, $\alpha = 1$, with $h(1) = 0$ and $h''(1) > 0$, so this is the minimum: for $\alpha \ne \beta$, $h(\alpha) > 0$.